# how to take input from a user on a google map of a boundary he/she draws

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geojson

I am developing a website and I am a very beginner to php.
this is my google map.
http://ceylonembedded.com/map2.php

I want a user to be able to draw a boundary when he accesses my site froma mobile or from a browser to be able to generate an alert by the system when something crosses the boundry.

Can someone please tell me what the better way to do this?

I understand I need to know good Google map API.
other than that do I have to lean JavaScript?
Or do I learn Jason? or any other technique?
A series of guidance would be so much appreciated.

Comment: I still havent received a good answer. is there anyone who would know how to do this?

Comment: Have you ever figured this out?  I'm in the process of doing something similar.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way would be to make the whole website a canvas in html5, and every frame, import the image from a offscreen google map. Then, you could draw whatever you'd want on your canvas using javascript; however, I cannot guide you through the process, it's just a hypothetical solution.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I dont wan step by step guidance. the idea I have a is too blurry. if you could tell me how i must do it, it will be very helpful.
and how do I obtain offline Google map images?
moreover, if I do so, by some means, I will have a problem using the Google API to implement tracking icons on it.
so any other idea?
thanks!